# Symfony 1.4 Routing: Fields from different classes

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How is it possible to create and match a route with fields from different classes?
Is it possible? Is there any custom routing class?

For example I have these two classes:

```
File:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), unique: true, notnull: true }
    ...

Link:
  columns:
    file_id: { type: bigint, notnull: true }
    ticket: { type: string(64), notnull: true }
  relations:
    File:
      local: file_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: links
  ...
```

Now suppose I want to create a route like this: `mysite.com/:ticket/:name`
As you can see, `ticket` is a field of `Link` table and `name` is a field of `File` table. Is there any way to create such links in symfony 1.4?

First solution is to change the primary key of the `File` table and set it to it's name. I know this, but I wonder if there exist a way to handle this through routing.

My goal is when I called getObject method, it returns a Link object with sent ticket, but the existence and relationship with sent file name should also be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC you can do something like that:

```
my_route:
  url: /:ticket/:name
  class: sfDoctrineRoute
  param: { module: yourModule, action: yourAction }
  options: { type: object, model: Link, method: findLinkWithSendTicket }
```

Then symfony should call `LinkTable::findLinkWithSendTicket` method and pass to it parameters, so you can use it to fetch object.

Links can be helpful:

- [sfDoctrineRoute.class.php](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/routing/sfDoctrineRoute.class.php#L104)
- [sfObjectRoute](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/10-Routing#chapter_10_sfobjectroute)